# How to block the api repeated request with in certain time limit

Tags: node.js, api

I am using Rest API with node js.

My requirement is that if I get repeated requests within a certain time interval, I need to block it for 15 minutes (because token expired in 15 mints).

My condition allow only 15 requests in 10 seconds from the same client. 
once you receive the 16th request in the 11th second from the same client then client is need to be black listed and gets a Forbidden status from then on – until their Token expires.
 Token expiry time limit is 15 mints from the time of token creation, this will be maintained in node session.

How to achieve this please help me any one I am using below method

```
var rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
var limiter = rateLimit({/* config */});
app.use('/users', limiter);
```

I am using default config values here. If I send repeated request then its says 429-Too Many Requests. After a few seconds its working no error response. Here I need to block the request from same place for 15 minutes, after 15 minutes token will be expired. I then want to continue the process then, creating a new token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide 2 things:

1. A time limit
2. How many requests you want to allow in that time limit

If you want to limit requests to a maximum of 15 every 10 seconds, you would configure `express-rate-limit` like so:

```
var rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
var limiter = rateLimit({
      windowMs: 10 * 1000, // 10 seconds
      max: 15,
});
app.use('/users', limiter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Token expiry time limit is 15 mints from the time of token creation, this will be maintained in session.
My condition allow only 15 requests in 10 seconds from the same client.
once you receive the 16th request in the 11th second from the same client then client is need to be black listed and gets a Forbidden status from then on – until their Token expires

Comment: What i want to do for this
My condition allow only 15 requests in 10 seconds from the same client. once you receive the 16th request in the 11th second from the same client then client is need to be black listed and gets a Forbidden status from then on – until their Token expires
Token expiry time limit is 15 mints from the time of token creation, this will be maintained in session.